# Display image inline with text in a Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu in a navbar where I want to display a small thumbnail avatar next to the menu text. I can get that part to work, but then the text runs out past the border of the dropdown. I have seen some examples of showing a font-awesome or glyphicon inline next to the hyperlink. But none using an image where the image is being resized.

It is using Bootstrap 3.3.5. Here is a link to the issue at hand: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fQKOCa5IXs)

Can someone shed some light on how to fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this solution.

```
   .dropdown-menu a.avatar img {
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

.dropdown-menu {min-width:300px}

@media screen and (max-widht: 780px) {
    dropdown-menu {
        max-width:100%
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/rs8yxpwz1r)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your solution works if the user's email address is fairly short. But if you get one of those crazy long email addresses, it still runs out past the end of the the dropdown. Do you know of a way to make the dropdown resize to accommodate the content, if the email address gets too long?